# How to get a random key value from a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object, hash

I have a Javascript hash of Spanish words/phrases and their English meanings:

```
  let phrases = {
    hola: "hello",
    adios: "bye",
  };
```

I want to select a random key. I have tried for a while, and my latest attempt hasn't worked and returns undefined:

```
  var keys = phrases.keys;
  var len = phrases.length;
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
  var key = phrases[rnd];
```

I've looked at other Stack Overflow answers but can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for. Any ideas please?

Comment: There is no `phrases.keys`, there is maybe `Object.keys(phrases)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) instead.

Try the following:

```js
const phrases = {
  hola: "hello",
  adios: "bye",
};

const keys = Object.keys(phrases);
const len = keys.length;
const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
const key = phrases[keys[rnd]];

console.log(key);
```

I hope this helps!